# Transaction not updating balance

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

Below is my code that I've written for a cash payment module. After the user presses Save, all entries in datagridview get affected as per column TYPE that has Debit and Credit and all entries work accordingly. The code is saving the data but not updating the account's balances.

What I need is accounts details get updated in cash payment (it working) and all balances get updated in Chart of Accounts.

```
con = New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
    con.Open()
    Dim cb As String = "insert into cashpayment(cashpaymentid,date,coa_id2,paymentfrom,coa_id,paymentto,amountdr,remarks,totalamount) Values (@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17,@d18,@d21,@d22)"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cb)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d12", CashPaymentidTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d13", DateDateTimePicker.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d14", Coa_id2TextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d15", PaymentfromTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d16", Coa_idTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d17", PaymenttoTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d18", AmountdrTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d21", RemarksTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d22", TotalamountTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteReader()
    con.Close()
    con = New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
    con.Open()
    Dim cb1 As String = "insert into [cashpayment_join](cpvidj,cashpaymentid,date,coafrom,paymentfrom,coato,paymentto,dr,type,description,userid) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11)"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cb1)
    cmd.Connection = con
    ' Prepare command for repeated execution
    cmd.Prepare()
    ' Data to be inserted
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", row.Cells(0).Value) 'cashpaymentid
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", row.Cells(1).Value) 'cashpaymentid
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", row.Cells(2).Value)  'date
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", row.Cells(3).Value)  'paymentto
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", row.Cells(4).Value)  'paymentfrom
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", row.Cells(5).Value)  'dr
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", row.Cells(6).Value)  'cr
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d8", row.Cells(7).Value)  'description
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d9", row.Cells(8).Value)  'total
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10", row.Cells(9).Value)  'total
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d11", row.Cells(10).Value)  'total
            '      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10", row.Cells(9).Value) 'userid
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        End If
    Next
    con.Close()


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        '  Using cn As New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
        Using cn1 As New SqlConnection(appx.myconnection)
            cn1.Open()
            Using com As New SqlCommand("", cn1)
                For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Type").Value = "Credit" Then
                        com.CommandText = "Update COA set opening_balance = opening_balance - @dra where AccountID=@ida"
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ida", row.Cells(5).Value)
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dra", row.Cells(7).Value)
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    ElseIf Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Type").Value = "Debit" Then
                        com.CommandText = "Update COA set opening_balance = opening_balance + @dr where AccountID=@id"
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.Cells(5).Value)
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dr", row.Cells(7).Value)
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End If

                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    Dim result1 As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Posted Successfully. Do you want to print", "Entry Posted Successfully", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    If result1 = DialogResult.No Then
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        Call AddNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e)
    ElseIf result1 = DialogResult.Yes Then
        cpvreport()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        Call AddNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e)
    End If
```

[image: datagrid image]

Comment: Are you sure your row cells are lining up properly? example... for your insert detail, cell 5 is your `dr` and cell 7 is the `description`, but in the update, cell 5 is the `id` and cell 7 is the `dr`. And the insert into `cashpayment_join` table, columns `coafrom,paymentfrom,coato,paymentto` don't line up in the loop when adding to the parameters.

Comment: yes , all data is saving as per insert details ... the update statement is only making issue becz All balance will effect as per column 8 (Type) like is row one in type is Debit, then the balance will me added to COA account and if Type is Credit then it will less the amount in COA, Also so if i have 1000 entries it will do transections as per type . i wrote the code but it only updating 1st row not all entries

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the grid?

Comment: here is image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDlzT.jpg

Comment: screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDlzT.jpg

Comment: Side Note 1 - When adding a parameter value from input be sure to convert that input into the expected type. Do not pass in the string value of a text box as the parameter value when the schema type it is being inserted into is of type decimal. Instead parse it in c# and add that value as the parameter's value.

Comment: Side Note 2 - Do not use `AddWithValue`, use `Add` instead.  Example: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(input.Text)`. This allows you to specify the parameter's type which can be important if there is ever ambiguity.

Comment: Side note 3 - Wrap your instances where the type implements `System.IDisposable` in `using` blocks which ensures the underlying resources are *always* released even if there is an exception. In this case wrap your instances of `SqlConnection` in using blocks (SqlCommand and DataTable also implement IDisposable)

Comment: noted igor...but what is the solution of my problem